# Inspecting element on wordpress website shows wrong line number

Tags: css, wordpress, element, inspect

Whenever I inspect an element on my wordpress website it shows the element as being on line 1 of `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ignite/style.min.css?ver=1.19` instead of the correct line in "style.css".

Can someone please let me know how to make my website use style.css rather than `style.min.css?ver1.9`?

Thanks.

Comment: Just comment the link out if you don't want to use the minified version.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Thanks, where will I find the link to comment out?

Comment: its better to user minified version on your production version of the site. rather unminified it using online tools,edit it and then again minifi  it and replace your css.min with this updated css file

Answer (score 1):

The script has been minified. Technically it's all on line 1. See if you cannot locate a version of the css that is not minified.

You can also use a minifier tool in reverse, take the unminfied cod and replace the css file with the inflated version. Run it again and then you'll be able to find the problem based on the line.

Minifier tool here:

http://cssminifier.com/

Comment: Thanks. I can see the unminified version and the minified version in my dreamweaver site. How do I make it use the unminified version?

Comment: I think for now it would be best if you just create a new stylesheet. Let's call it "style.css". Comment out the original like so: <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ignite/style.min.css?ver=1.19" />--> And add the new one in: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ignite/style.css" />

Comment: Cheers. Do you know what the file will be called in my wordpress site that specifies that link?

Comment: Would copy pasting the unminified code into the minified version be bad practice?